# cannot import name import_by_path

Tags: python, django

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://ec2-145-28-57-102.compute-1.amazonaws.com/reports/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:

cannot import name import_by_path

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/storage/**init**.py in , line 2
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:

['/var/www/stacks/apps/project/apps',
 '/usr/lib64/python26.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info',
 '/var/www/stacks/apps/']

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  250.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_url_patterns
  279.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_urlconf_module
  274.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/var/www/stacks/apps/project/apps/reports/urls.py" in <module>
  8. from views import (project_report, project_report_new, CustomReportList, delete_custom_report,
File "/var/www/stacks/apps/project/apps/reports/views.py" in <module>
  15. from forms import PROJECTReportForm, PROJECTReportFormNew, CrossCheckForm 
File "/var/www/stacks/apps/project/apps/reports/forms.py" in <module>
  29. from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in <module>
  13. from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.storage import get_storage
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/storage/__init__.py" in <module>
  2. from django.utils.module_loading import import_by_path

Exception Type: ImportError at /reports/
Exception Value: cannot import name import_by_path
```

Exception Type: ImportError at /reports/
Exception Value: cannot import name import_by_path

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.module_loading.import_by_path) state that `import_by_path` is new in Django 1.6, while the question mentions Django 1.3.1. Perhaps you have both versions installed? Check all directories on Python path.

Answer (score 1):

import_by_path is deprecated from Django 1.7
So this is actually because of bug in the way that Django versions are detected:

```
    if django.get_version() >= "1.7":
        from django.utils.module_loading import import_string
    else:
        from django.utils.module_loading import import_by_path as import_string
```

will not work for Django >= 1.10 because of the lexical compare.

need to edit and fork the library or in your local env you can change as follows:

> Edit site-packages/omnibus/management/commands/omnibusd.py

```
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string as import_by_path
```